# Error when using uglifier to minify the min.js file in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, minify, uglifyjs, pdfmake

I have a rails project, which includes a [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) js plugin. I put the `pdfmake.min.js` file in the `assets\javascripts` folder and added it into `application.js`:

```
//= require pdfmake.min
```

In staging server, I have related asset settings:

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true
```

However, I got an error on staging server:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: n
```

This error is not on development environment, so I am guessing it is caused by the js compile. To be detailed, caused when using `uglifier`:

**related source code**:

```
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(Buffer) {// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.7.1
    (function() {
      var DecodeStream, iconv;

      try {
        iconv = __webpack_require__(87);
      } catch (_error) {}

      DecodeStream = (function() {
        var key;

        function DecodeStream(buffer) {
          this.buffer = buffer;
          this.pos = 0;
          this.length = this.buffer.length;
        }

        ......

      })();

      module.exports = DecodeStream;

    }).call(this);
```

**min.js and the same in local without uglifier**

```
function(t, e, n) {
        (function(e) {
            (function() {
                var r,
                    i;
                try {
                    i = n(84)
                } catch (t) {}
                r = function() {
                    function t(t) {
                        this.buffer = t, this.pos = 0, this.length = this.buffer.length
                    }
                    var n;
                    ......
                }(), t.exports = r
            }).call(this)
```

**code in application.js after uglifier in staging**

```
function(A, t, e) {
        (function(A) {
            (function() {
                var t,
                    i;
                try {
                    i = e(84)
                } catch (n) {}
                t = function() {
                    function t(A) {
                        this.buffer = A, this.pos = 0, this.length = this.buffer.length
                    }
                    var e;
                    ......
                }(), n.exports = t
            }).call(this)
```

According to the above code, we can find that the `uglifier` assign both `module` and `Buffer` to `A` incorrectly. How can I fix this?

I have some thoughts:

- Disable `uglifier` on staging. Is it good for staging and production?
- Replace the `pdfmake.min.js` to `pdfmake.js`.
- Any other thoughts?

Comment: what version of the uglifier gem are you using? Occasional bugs have been fixed in there. Either way though I'd go with Using the plain pdfmake.js before uglification. I have had similar issues in the past with multiple passes of minification that you could be experiencing here.

Comment: Hi @Phil, my uglifier gem's version is 2.5.0. I am considering plain pdfmake.js as well.

Comment: ooh, that sounds a bit old to me. In a Rails 4.2 project I'm working on my uglifier is 3.2.0, which I believe is the most up to date. It is working fine for me with mostly non-minified JS (one simple one is minified and seems fine). Might be worth a shot upgrading on your dev machine to see.

Comment: @Phil Actually, I replaced the minified js to plain one, and it works fine now. I cannot find the reason why `uglifier` wrongly minify the minified js file, but it could be a solution. You can make it as an answer.

Comment: I'm pleased it worked for you. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on previous experience, I have found that previously minified Javascript can cause uglifier some issues. This may be related to older bugs in uglifier where if it was run with multiple passes over the same code it would fail.

For a reliable result, use the unminified pdfmake.js so that uglifier should have no issues.

Also, given that your version of the uglifier gem is from 2014 (see https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/releases?after=v2.5.2 ) you should definitely consider upgrading the uglifier gem to avoid other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Phil's answer. I can confirm that it caused by the uglifier and the newest `3.2` will solve this issue. In this answer, I will dig more into it.

I created a new rails project and import `pdfmake.min.js`, the `uglifier` version I use `2.5` which will also cause the issue. I tested the version from `2.5` to `3.2` and found that the `3.1` fixed the problem.

Checking the commit from `3.0` to `3.1`, I found that it updated the `UglifyJS` to `2.7`. I also tested by configuring gem with `git ref`, and verified that this update fixed the issue.

In conclusion, always update to the latest version. If still not solving the issue, replace the minified js to the plain one.